# loop through all files in folder, check if first part of filename matches any files in a diff folder-move if not

Tags: loops, batch-file, move

I have 75,000 files for a karaoke system. For each song there's the music (`.mp3`) and the lyrics (`.cdg`). So, for each song there are two files.

```bat
Artist - SongName [Karaoke Brand1].mp3
Artist - SongName [Karaoke Brand1].cdg
```

The issue is that some songs have many versions (5-10). `Brand1` is the best, so I've just used standard windows search to filter all files of that brand and cut them and pasted them manually which gave me 25,000 files in the new curated older.

But there are a lot of songs in the original folder that `Brand1` doesn't have a version of. I prefer `Brand2` and `Brand3` in this case, but not every song is done by both. Regardless every song is at least done by one or the other.

I want to loop through all remaining MP3 files in (no need to look at ALL since the `.cdg`s are the same name with a different extension):

```bat
"D:/Karaoke/All"
```

and and take the filename BEFORE the square brackets [wildcard?] and see if I already have a version of it in:

```bat
"D:/Karaoke/Curated"
```

If there is do nothing and move to next file.

If there isn't move `Brand2` if it exists (full filename `.mp3` AND `.cdg`) to `D:/Karaoke/Curated`.

If `Brand2` doesn't exist, see if Brand3 does and use that one instead

The file naming is the same for all Brands, just the text inside the brackets `[Brand]` will be different.

**EDIT**
what i've come up with so far

```bat
            @echo off
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            for %%i in (*.mp3) do (
                for /f "tokens=1 delims=[" %%a in ("%%i") DO (
            REM get "checkable name first"
            REM     echo %%a
                    set checkName=%%a
            REM     echo !checkName!
                )
                echo !checkName!
            )
            exit
```

Comment: Please note that Stack OverFlow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: i know what Stack OverFlow is and isnt. I help people daily in game dev discords and forums. I needed a bit of help for a personal project and thought it would be simple for a one time script to just do it in windows. thanks anyway then. I'll work it out myself. not a friendly bunch here huh.  happy new year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution according to your requirements:

```bat
@echo off

cd /d "D:\Karaoke\All"
for %%A IN ("*.mp3") do (
    for /f "delims=[]" %%B IN ("%%~nA") do (
        dir /A "D:\Karaoke\Curated\%%B*" >nul 2>&1
        if errorlevel 1 (
            if exist "%%B[Karaoke Brand2].mp3" (
                move "%%B[Karaoke Brand2].*" "D:\Karaoke\Curated\"
            ) else (
                if exist "%%B[Karaoke Brand3].mp3" (
                    move "%%B[Karaoke Brand3].*" "D:\Karaoke\Curated\"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: The `dir /b D:\Karaoke\Curated | findstr /c:"%%B"` will without need scan the whole dir and invoke a 2nd cmd through the pipe. Simply use instead `dir /b "D:\Karaoke\Curated\%%B*" >Nul 2>&1` this will equally trigger the errorlevel. You might as well append `|findstr /i "Brand[23]` to check if one of the desired alternative brands exists.